# Hybrid App Context Switch [NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_com.reqi.will, FLUTTER] not found

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, appium, hybrid-mobile-app, appium-flutter

When I do "getContext" handles, I get following result
`[NATIVE_APP, WEBVIEW_com.reqi.will, FLUTTER]`

I am unable to switch to **WEBVIEW_com.reqi.will**, throws compatible exception..!!

But I am able to switch to `WEBVIEW_chrome` which is not present in context list, able to switch and work with it.

Why and How this is happening??

FYI,
Hydrid Futter App with Web & Native.
ChromeDriver 119.xxx.xx